# How to left join dataframes on date in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two dataframes.
card_transactions_df dataframe:

```
+----------+-----------------+------+--------+
|   tr_date|balance_available|tr_ccy|card_ccy|
+----------+-----------------+------+--------+
|2022-03-23|            44.93|   944|     944|
|2022-03-23|           609.23|   944|     756|
|2022-03-23|             2.15|   944|     944|
|2022-03-23|            250.0|   944|     840|
|2022-03-17|           108.79|   944|     944|
|2022-03-17|             8.14|   944|     944|
|2022-03-17|          1753.46|   944|     944|
+----------+-----------------+------+--------+
```

schema:

```
root
 |-- tr_date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- balance_available: float (nullable = true)
 |-- tr_ccy: short (nullable = true)
 |-- card_ccy: short (nullable = true)
```

and currency_df:

```
+--------+------------+------+
|CURRENCY|CREATED_DATE|AMOUNT|
+--------+------------+------+
|     978|  2022-03-23|1.8101|
|     826|  2022-03-23|2.1392|
|     981|  2022-03-23|0.5583|
|     840|  2022-03-23|   1.7|
|     643|  2022-03-23|0.0229|
|     756|  2022-03-23|1.7658|
|     949|  2022-03-23|0.1148|
|     643|  2022-03-23|0.0225|
|     978|  2022-03-17|1.8237|
|     949|  2022-03-17| 0.115|
|     756|  2022-03-17|1.7733|
|     840|  2022-03-17|   1.7|
|     981|  2022-03-17|0.5595|
|     826|  2022-03-17|2.1693|
|     840|  2022-03-17|   1.7|
```

schema:

```
root
 |-- CURRENCY: short (nullable = true)
 |-- CREATED_DATE: date (nullable = true)
 |-- AMOUNT: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to left join currency_df dataframe to card_transactions_df dataframe on date and currency:

```
card_transactions_df_joined = card_transactions_df.join(currency_df, 
                                                       (card_transactions_df.tr_ccy == currency_df.CURRENCY) &
                                                         (card_transactions_df.tr_date == currency_df.CREATED_DATE),
                                                        "left")
```

result:

```
+----------+-----------------+------+--------+--------+------------+------+
|   tr_date|balance_available|tr_ccy|card_ccy|CURRENCY|CREATED_DATE|AMOUNT|
+----------+-----------------+------+--------+--------+------------+------+
|2022-03-23|            69.13|   840|     840|    null|        null|  null|
|2022-03-23|            23.51|   840|     944|    null|        null|  null|
|2022-03-23|          1680.17|   840|     840|    null|        null|  null|
|2022-03-23|             5.92|   840|     944|    null|        null|  null|
|2022-03-23|           401.66|   840|     840|    null|        null|  null|
|2022-03-23|          8399.21|   978|     978|    null|        null|  null|
|2022-03-23|           582.33|   978|     944|    null|        null|  null|
|2022-03-23|           105.41|   840|     944|    null|        null|  null|
|2022-03-23|            345.9|   840|     840|    null|        null|  null|
|2022-03-23|             5.86|   840|     944|    null|        null|  null|
|2022-03-23|            128.2|   840|     944|    null|        null|  null|
|2022-03-23|          2142.71|   840|     840|    null|        null|  null|
|2022-03-23|           926.96|   840|     944|    null|        null|  null|
|2022-03-23|           583.37|   840|     840|    null|        null|  null|
|2022-03-23|            700.0|   840|     840|    null|        null|  null|
|2022-03-23|           178.49|   840|     944|    null|        null|  null|
|2022-03-23|             2.13|   840|     840|    null|        null|  null|
|2022-03-23|            38.18|   840|     840|    null|        null|  null|
|2022-03-23|           536.17|   840|     944|    null|        null|  null|
|2022-03-23|           358.87|   840|     944|    null|        null|  null|
+----------+-----------------+------+--------+--------+------------+------+
```

All values in CURRENCY, CREATED_DATE and AMOUNT columns are `Null`. But it shouldn't be. If I join without a date, they aren't `Null`:

```
+----------+-----------------+------+--------+--------+------------+------+
|   tr_date|balance_available|tr_ccy|card_ccy|CURRENCY|CREATED_DATE|AMOUNT|
+----------+-----------------+------+--------+--------+------------+------+
|2022-03-23|            69.13|   840|     840|     840|  2021-09-13|   1.7|
|2022-03-23|            69.13|   840|     840|     840|  2021-08-04|   1.7|
|2022-03-23|            69.13|   840|     840|     840|  2021-05-24|   1.7|
|2022-03-23|            69.13|   840|     840|     840|  2022-03-05|   1.7|
|2022-03-23|            69.13|   840|     840|     840|  2022-02-11|   1.7|
|2022-03-23|            69.13|   840|     840|     840|  2021-11-12|   1.7|
```

How to make join correctly?

Comment: There is no common entries card_transactions_df tr_ccy and currency_df.CURRENCY so obviously you will end up getting nulls for currency_df columns. can you add what result your getting and what result is expected?

Comment: or maybe you have null values in either `tr_ccy` or `CURRENCY`

Comment: @Ajaykumar, I've added the info to the question.

Comment: as @pltc mentioned did you check for nulls?

Comment: @Ajaykumar, `card_transactions_df_joined.where(col("CURRENCY").isNotNull() | col("AMOUNT").isNotNull()).show()` doesn't return any rows

Comment: how many rows in your dataframes? can you be able to share it?

Comment: check for nulls before joining for tr_date, tr_ccy, CURRENCY, CREATED_DATE.